# Using nginx, I need my "bad user agent" map not to block my rss xml file

Tags: nginx, rss

I use a map in nginx to block bad user agents (nutch and such). Some RSS readers have funny user agents, so I rather not run the map on that directory.

Stripping down the nginx.conf file:

```
server{
location / {
 root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mydomain/public_html;
        if ($badagent)     { return 403; }
}
location = /feeds {
        try_files $uri $uri.xml $uri/ ;
       }
}
```

The "=" should force an exact match, but the badagent map is checked.

Comment: Are you trying to not block /feeds , or any url that begins with /feeds ? like /feeds/hello ?

Answer (score 1):

```
server{

    location ~ ^/feeds {
            try_files $uri $uri.xml $uri/ ;
    }


    location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mydomain/public_html;
        if ($badagent)     { return 403; }
    }


}
```

What I think you want is anything under /feeds, not /feeds itself , location = /feeds only will match example.com/feeds , and location ~ ^/feeds will match anything beggining with /feeds*(example.com/feeds/facebook  example.com/feeds/myspace . Hope I helped